# How to split a list of 35 items into a matrix 7 columns and 5 rows in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I want to split my results, which are a list of 35 items, into a matrix of 7 columns and 5 rows where the first 5 values in the list correspond to the values in the 5 rows of the first column, items 6-10 of the results list are the values of the 5 rows of the second column, and so on for the 7 columns.  I've been trying many different approaches, but they all end up putting the first 5 values of the first row... My current code is below:

```
num_rows <- 5
num_columns <- 7

result_matrix <- matrix(unlist(results), nrow = num_rows, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: Remove `byrow = TRUE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `byrow = FALSE` or remove it, since `FALSE` is its default value.

```
> results <- 1:35
> result_matrix <- matrix(unlist(results), nrow = num_rows, byrow = FALSE)
> result_matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21   26   31
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22   27   32
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23   28   33
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24   29   34
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25   30   35
```